# getting this error while running a hibernate code

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.11 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Hibernate: select max(ID) from user
Hibernate: insert into user (Last_NAME, First_NAME, STREET, LOGIN_ID, password, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Sat Jan 14 13:36:09 IST 2023 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...

EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:
```

**BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION:**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:842)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:821)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.quit(NativeProtocol.java:1312)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.quit(NativeSession.java:182)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:1750)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.close(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
    at com.DTO.TestUserDTO.main(TestUserDTO.java:28)
```

I try to run a Hibernate program using XML when I try to run it I get this error. How to solve it?

Comment: Need to improve formatting

Comment: You can take a look at the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) guide. You should also try to improve your question's title ("this error") - be specific. There is more guidance in [ask].